# Where does the proof of this fact use that a relative maximum is in the interior of the unit disc?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I was looking for some help about a question in my Advanced Calculus course, about a function $u(\vec{x}):\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the trace of the Hessian of the function is $\geq 0$ for all $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

The question is about showing that the maximum of such a function restricted to the closed unit disc must take its maximum at the boundary.

I looked at this answer:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2643384/489963

It's a good answer and it makes the whole idea clear, except for one thing. 
The crux of the argument is to assume that a slightly modified version of $u$, $$u^{\epsilon}=u(\vec{x})+\epsilon||u(\vec{x})||^{2}$$
 assumes its maximum on the closed unit disc in the INTERIOR of the disc, and then to find a contradiction.

I don't know what I'm missing here, but I don't see where the argument uses the fact that the assumed maximum $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ is *inside* the disc. Couldn't you assume that the maximum was anywhere at all in the closed unit disc, and then get the same contradiction?

The point is I feel like you could just as easily use the logic of the proof to assume a max of $u^{\epsilon}$ on the boundary and show that’s impossible too. Using the logic of the proof, let’s assume $u^{\epsilon}$ takes its max on the boundary—then $\Delta u^{\epsilon}= 4 \epsilon >0$ by construction of $u^{\epsilon}$. But if this is a maximum point $\Delta u^{\epsilon} \leq 0$. Therefore $u^{\epsilon}$ must assume its maximum on unit closed disc somewhere in the interior. But it doesn’t...

Please help me see the error of my ways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof shows that $u^\epsilon$ cannot attain maximum in the interior, it doesn't show that $u$ cannot attain maximum in the interior.

If $u^\epsilon$ attains a maximum in the interior, it satisfies $\Delta u^\epsilon \le 0. $

It is possible when $u$ is a constant and you won't find a contradiction if you assume it is in the interior.

Comment: I edited the question, maybe it’s clearer now what I’m asking

Comment: $\Delta u^\epsilon \le 0$ is a property that we conclude if it is a maximum in the interior, we can't make such conclusion at the boundary.

Comment: But don’t you conclude this about a maximum anywhere? Any local maximum should have this property, regardless of where the point lies in the set, no?

Comment: not really, for example consider a strongly convex function over a compact set. the maximum must exists at the boundary, its second derivative is positive.

Comment: I really don’t understand what you’re saying. What I’m saying is I don’t think in the proof we use any property of interior points. That’s why I’m confused.

Comment: Consider the one dimensional case, consider the function $u=x^2$ where the domain is $[-1,1]$, where are the maximum points attained? can you check the second derivative at those points? must they be negative?

Comment: So I can only make the conclusion about $\Delta u^{\epsilon} \leq 0$ if the maximum point is an interior point?

Comment: yup, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!